# How to transfer a file from one system to another system in a single command?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-sharing

How to transfer a file from one system to another system easily?In my company employees will always ask us to transfer files from one system A to  system B and so on. What we do is first we access system A through samba and copy the required files and then we access the system B through samba and paste the files there.Is there any easy and quick way of transferring of files from one system to another system?Any GUI will be preferable, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ssh to transfer files.
So you can transfer a file like this:

```
scp /home/user/examplefile otheruser@192.168.1.101:/home/otheruser/
```

This will transfer `examplefile` to `/home/otheruser`

If you dont like to use commands, you can just use nautilus, which supports the ssh-protocol. The remote location appears just like a normal directory and you can copy files there.

To access the remote location, open Nautilus and look under **File > Connect to Server...** then choose the location you want.

Comment: Any GUI tool to handle this task??.Such that i will browse the files in System A and then drag it to system B..

Comment: yes, as i said with the build in ssh-protocol of nautilus. It's then like a normal directory, where you can drag and drop files.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of doing this that we did in a company I used to work in was that there was a network shared folder that everyone could use on a temporary basis. That way you don't need to copy files for people, they can just put their files on the central shared directory and then they can access it from any of the other machines on the floor.

If there are security concerns then you might have to give everyone their own passworded folder on shared directory, which involves a little more back work on your part but will save you a lot of work in the long term.

If people have to ask you to move files around they might as well use a USB stick, much better to let them do it themselves on the network.